# run cmd.exe - batch file through main form, with display of the path of the command + the args

Tags: c#

run cmd.exe - batch file through main form, with display of the path of the command + the args

this code runs the batch file without displaying the command line

```
ProcessStartInfo _processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(
                 "CMD.exe", "/c" + 
                 Path.GetFullPath(@"..\Scripts\" + fileName + ".bat"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Arguments` Property:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.arguments.aspx

```
ProcessStartInfo _processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(
                 "CMD.exe", "/c" + 
                 Path.GetFullPath(@"..\Scripts\" + fileName + ".bat"));
_processStartInfo.Arguments = arguments;
Process p = Process.Start(_processStartInfo);
```

To display the path to the bat file in the bat itself, use

`echo %~f0`. To display the argument list, you could try `echo %*`

Comment: the batch file work good but without displaying the command line
for example:
C:\Users\skanerx\Desktop\ScriptCreator\bin\Scripts>my_script.bat

"+ the args" is an unnecessary extra